# Git don't push on windows 10

Tags: git, powershell, github, cmd, windows-10

I installed git bash. Later added to the path, and all seems to work, except when pushing the files **at the exact moment of introducing the password** the keyboard become unresponsive every time using cmd, cmder or powershell.
Still git bash works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound obvious, but have you tried typing the password (even if it seem unresponsive) and hitting Enter? There's a [security] reason why characters are not shown while you are typing your password in the command prompt.

Comment: You're right it wasn't really a problem, it does the work but you can't see the dots while typing so it confused me. Thanks!